# Assembly code skipping a line?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Why is my assembly code skipping a line? It keeps skipping the line `mov AX,A`

```
org 100h
count equ 2
A DW 5
B DW 6
Y0 DW ?
Y1 DW ?    
mov AX,A     
add AX,B
sub AX,count
mov Y0,AX
mov BX,B
neg BX
add BX,count
mov Y1,BX 
ret
```

Comment: You don't want to put data in code execution path ... move them to after the code.

Answer (score 6):

Let's see what *code bytes* these *instruction mnemonics* would assemble to:

```
               org 100h
               count equ 2
05 00          A DW 5
06 00          B DW 6
00 00          Y0 DW ?
00 00          Y1 DW ?    
A1 00 01       mov AX,A       ;NASM "mov ax, [A]"
03 06 02 01    add AX,B       ;NASM "add ax, [B]"
83 E8 02       sub AX,count
...
```

The code bytes are on the left; the instruction mnemonics (the part you feed to the assembler) are on the right. All looks good, right?

Well, now let's see what happens when we assemble and then disassemble the code:

```
05 00 06           add ax,0x600
00 00              add [bx+si],al
00 00              add [bx+si],al
00 B8 00 01        add [bx+si+0x100],bh
05 02 01           add ax,0x102
83 E8 02           sub ax,byte +0x2
```

Wait…what happened?! The bytes (on the left) are the same, but the instruction mnemonics are all different! They're not the same ones you originally wrote!

What happened is, the *data* declarations that were at the top of your code were all dutifully translated into bytes by the assembler, but then the disassembler translated those (data) bytes back into *executable code*. It didn't realize they were data, so it tried to interpret them as instructions to be executed. This resulted not only in the incorrect instructions, but also introduced a [frameshift mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frameshift_mutation) that messed up everything downstream.

So it's not actually "skipping" the instruction `mov ax, a`. That instruction isn't even *there* anymore, as far as the computer can tell. It is executing the instructions that you see in the second block of code. Basically, it is executing nonsense. Remember: in assembler, everything is just bytes!

The solution should be obvious: don't mix data declarations in with your executable code. The best thing to do would be to move the data down to the *bottom*, below all of your executable code, where execution will never get:

```
org 100h
count equ 2

mov AX,A     
add AX,B
sub AX,count
mov Y0,AX
mov BX,B
neg BX
add BX,count
mov Y1,BX 
ret

A DW 5
B DW 6
Y0 DW ?
Y1 DW ?
```

Introducing whitespace helps to break things up into logical chunks, making the code more readable. Notice that I've left the `ORG` directive at the top, because it needs to be there. I also didn't move the `EQU` directive to the bottom. It's okay to leave that there because it just defines an assemble-time constant. As you can see from the very beginning, it isn't translated into any bytes in the resulting machine code.

If you didn't want to move the data for whatever reason, then you would have to insert an instruction to jump over it:

```
org 100h
count equ 2

jmp Begin

A DW 5
B DW 6
Y0 DW ?
Y1 DW ?    

Begin:
    mov AX,A     
    add AX,B
    sub AX,count
    mov Y0,AX
    mov BX,B
    neg BX
    add BX,count
    mov Y1,BX 
    ret
```

Comment: Great descriptive answer.  Very nice job.

Comment: The code (05 02 01) that you've written for `add AX, B` is wrong! You've used the encoding for `ADD AX, imm16', when it's `ADD r16, r/m16` that you want. So the opcode becomes 03h resulting in a 4-byte instruction.

Comment: That's weird, @Fifoernik. I'm not sure how I could have gotten the encoding wrong. I ran this through NASM, assembling a 16-bit binary, first correctly-written and then incorrectly-written, disassembling the results each time. (In other words, I didn't do it off the top of my head!) I'm not sure why it would have used the wrong encoding for the instruction. Feel free to edit the answer and fix it. Or I'll try to remember to come back and revisit it when I get a chance.

Comment: "I ran this through NASM" Herein lies the problem! The code snippet presented by the OP follows MASM syntax. (eg. `mov Y0,AX` wouldn't make sense for NASM) I'll edit the answer accordingly. For absolute accuracy, the disassembly would have to change also but I don't think that it would matter a great deal!

Comment: Well, yes, I did obviously have to adjust the syntax from MASM to NASM, so that instruction would have become `mov [Y0], ax`. I don't have access to a version of MASM that can generate 16-bit code. Although there are a *surprising* number of questions about it. Anyway, thanks for the edit. @Fifoernik

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code you have mixed operation codes with data definitions. This is completely wrong, due to the fact that your Assembler is going to assume that these data definitions are mnemonics, messing around the code. To see it just download a Hex Editor and see the Hex format of your code. Then find a Disassembler and try to disassemble the hex formated code. You will see that the code shown by the Disassembler will be way more different from what you have typed in your code. In other words the line`mov AX, A` is not skipped, rather than assumed to be another op code.